Why does my monitor shut off / enter sleep mode when I try to install Linux?
So I've been trying to install Linux on one of my SSDs, but whenever I get past grub to get to the graphic installation, my monitor shuts off and enters sleep mode. I'm not sure what causes this. I've been trying to change a bunch of different settings in my BIOS, such as secure boot and UEFI/CSM. My motherboard is ROG B-350-F Gaming. My USB installation format is MBR and I have CSM enabled with Legacy & UEFI support. Boot from storage is set to UEFI driver first. Secure boot is ON, but I'm not sure how to turn it off. Secure boot type is set to "Windows UEFI mode". The alternative is "Other OS" in BIOS. SSD is in GPT format. So far, I've tried Arch Linux and Fedora KDE, but none of them let me get to the installation part.
Specs:
CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5800x
GPU: NVIDIA 1050 TI

Do NOT enable CSM. You want UEFI mode since 2012! "Other OS" very likely means Secure Boot OFF. So, try that because you have a Nvidia GPU that may need proprietary drivers. Also, if you're having this sort of difficulties on top of the poor understanding of UEFI, I suggest Arch and even Fedora is too much. Unless you have a very compelling reason to use one or the other, DON'T. Start with beginner friendly distros like Ubuntu (and make sure to select the option to install 3rd party drivers; (...)

(...) with Ubuntu you can certainly keep Secure Boot ON for the installation, worse case scenario you'll have to boot the live session using the "safe graphics" option). At the end of the day it's very simple but if you think anyone without prior basic knowledge (discussed above) can do it, think again.

CSM was enabled by default with both UEFI and Legacy support. If I disable this, will I still be able to boot into my windows partition (GPT)?

Absolutely. Windows strictly requires GPT for UEFI mode. So, if you have Windows in a GPT drive that means it was correctly installed in UEFI mode as it happens since more than a decade ago.

Needless to say, if you don't know what you're doing then don't! Use a virtual machine instead or just test the distro in a live session (again, special "safe graphics" options when available or additional kernel parameters like nomodeset might be necessary to boot the live session with the desktop).

So I did disable CSM and Secure Boot. It does boot into Windows. But now when I hit F2 I can't get into BIOS. I don't know if the system boots up too fast or something.

Yes, it boots faster but not too fast that you can't access UEFI (BIOS isn't used since 2012) the normal way with the designated key. However, if you're unable to do it in time and you need to access the settings again you can do it from Windows.

I tried holding shift while restarting and then navigating to UEFI Firmware Settings. It restarts but then my monitor shuts off and enters sleep mode, and it boots back to Windows 10 without entering BIOS.

At this point, I just regret changing anything in BIOS. I guess I'll stay with Windows 10 for now, lol.

Clearly this is over your head, as expected -and- discussed above. Yes, there's a few things to learn first and you can try Linux safely in a virtualized environment. Now, Arch is hard even for experts.

"I've been trying to install Linux on one of my SSDs, but whenever I get past grub to get to the graphic installation," Most versions of Linux have an installer, and do not use grub. Try following, step-by-step, directions for running Linux from USB, and then installing it, such as this for Ubuntu:https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started .

@DrMoishePippik They do use GRUB even when booting the live session. The problem here, I suppose, is the Nvidia graphics.
